# Git: testing PHP script locally when connecting to a database

Tags: git

I am setting up Git and trying to use this. We have a development server, which holds all websites that we work on. Our projects use PHP, MySQL and Apache to function. This is all installed on the development server. However, my question is: how can I do testing on the local machines when I use Git? After all, I sync the projects and they all download to individual machines that do not necessarily have Apache/PHP/MySQL installed. Is the usual way to always commit and sync again with the development server, in order to test code? Feels rather inconvenient! Or is the common way to install local software just as on the server, so we can test without having to syncing every minute...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't do PHP, but I would say **never ever depend on a common dev server in this way**!! To answer your question, yes, all the required services need to run on each developer's machine. To help alleviate problems that crop up due to per-machine environment deviations, take a look at [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/).

P.S. This isn't really a git question. It's just a general process question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is maybe create a different branch called "dev-build" then have that sync on the dev server. The common way is to have non-public facing apache and mysql on your local computers